# Record deletion Error "unknown column id in where clause" ActiveJDBC

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

When I delete a record it shows an weird error,

"unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'. DELETE FROM tableName WHERE id='' null"

Something like that. The error seems to be self explanatory, BUT in my table I dont have a column id.

Table Structure:

- Code
- Name
- UserGroup

Why is ActiveJDBC searching an column id?

The error disappears when I added column id in my table. But still its weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a requirement of the framework. Did you read the documentation: http://javalite.io/surrogate_primary_keys ?

If you want to delete the parent, and then children with it, there are many ways to do this. One is to use the framework: 
http://javalite.io/delete_cascade

The other is to use a DB mechanism: [MySQL delete on cascade](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20delete%20on%20cascade&oq=mysql%20delete%20on%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3968j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Additionally, please really study relationships and read the docs before imoplementing: http://javalite.io/one_to_many_associations

Good luck!